# Need Help in Formatting Questions having Down Vote

Tags: support

I know I should not ask this question here. But I do not find any other way to contact the moderators.

Becasue of some bad questions I got blocked in `Stack Overflow` from posting new questions. I'm getting this error message

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more

After going through the `Help Centre`

> The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your existing posts; do not just post the same question again. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried. Reading your question out loud to yourself can help you understand what it sounds like to others. Here are some additional tips for writing good, useful questions:

The only thing that I can figure out to get `Up Votes` is by formatting previous question, that have negative reviews. But It has very less chances to get `Up Votes`. I've formatted and waited for an year But still Blocked. What should I do, I can not directly contact moderatres also.

Comment: You are not blocked from asking questions on [cs.se].

Comment: **Read the whole message**. Formatting is not your main problem. But do format your posts properly, in particular [do not use code formatting for random words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right).

Comment: you must have some deleted questions which are downvoted; *those* are what you want to improve/rewrite and try to get turned around

Comment: There's gotta be something I'm missing here.  Your non-deleted contributions don't have a net negative score. My guess is that you want to really improve your deleted contributions.

Answer (score 6):

Your questions aren't getting downvoted or closed because of formatting issues. They're getting downvoted and closed because they're poor questions: for example, off-topic ([1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38368/getting-started-with-python), [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38364/9550)), nonspecific requests for a lot of information ([3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38337/digital-image-processing)) and requests for corrections to attempted solutions ([4](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37700/9550), [5](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37854/solving-recurrence-relations-3)).

It's a little unfortunate that the help centre seems to concentrate on formatting. Your formatting is fine and, frankly, unless the formatting is so terrible that people can't even figure out what you're trying to say, bad formatting isn't going to be the major issue. If I see a question where the only significant problem is bad formatting, I'll just edit it to fix that, and lots of other people do the same.

Comment: I didn't even get any down-vote or close but still I see this message `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.` Why is it so?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Please see the link at the top of the page to the question that this one is a duplicate of.